# group by multiple fileds and order by count of group in python/django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Please help me in getting the result of below in django/python

```
SELECT u,v,x,y,z,count(1) FROM table1 group by  u,v,x,y,z order by  5,6;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by `order by 5,6`, I assume you have columns with that name...

Anyway, it should work like this:

```
results = MyModelForTable1.objects.values('u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z').annotate(Count('u')).order_by('5', '6')
```